# Grails logging: Multiple loggers and appenders

Tags: grails, logging

I am trying to configure a Grails (2.2.0) app to have a log file for a specific package and then use the console output for everything else.  I also want to make sure that nothing that goes to the log file also goes to the console (keep them totally separate).  Reading through [the docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/conf.html) I am still a bit confused on how to get this done.  Could someone help out with an example that accomplishes this (using the log4j DSL)?

Comment: have you thought about digging deeper into `log4j` and read the docs over there (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/)?

Comment: ... and here are some examples from the net which should help you gain some more knowledge about the `log4j` configuration in Grails projects. See http://snipplr.com/view/63391/grails-log4j-for-different-environments--an-example/ or http://grails-dev.blogspot.co.at/2012/09/setting-up-log4j-configuration-in.html

Answer (score 4):

I got this working with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995534/send-log-output-to-different-files-in-grails-1-3-2).  Here's what I ended up with in my Config.groovy:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        console name: 'stdout', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %x %-5p %c{2} - %m%n')

        rollingFile name: 'extraAppender',
                conversionPattern: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %x %-5p %c{2} - %m%n',
                maxFileSize: 1024,
                file: '/tmp/logs/extra.log'
    }

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    trace  additivity: false, extraAppender: 'extraLogger'
}
```

Then in the class that's supposed to use the extraLogger, I just go the logger like this:

```
def extraLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger('extraLogger')
```

That lets me log more things to the console and some other specific things to another log file, without any of those specific things ending up in the console log.

Comment: +1: this is probably the cleanest approach.  With careful manipulation of additivity etc you could possibly get everything for package `foo.bar` into the extra log, but then you'd have to also specifically re-assign every `foo.bar.baz` subpackage back to the `stdout` appender.  The separate logger approach is much simpler and less fragile.

Comment: I wouldn't go this way, as it would limit the way I can fetch different loggers for packages/classes and forces me to have two logger objects around if I want to get some 'extra' information, but if you're good to go with it everything's allright :)

Comment: In my case, having the 2 loggers is exactly what I needed.  I'm sure there are plenty of cases where this would not fit what others need though.

Comment: @user605331 didn't want to offend you with my message, just add my 2 cents to this topic ;)